# Correct approach to design database schema in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, schema

In my application There will be list of **programs**, each program will contains list of **sessions**, and each session will contains list of **worksheets**. In simpler way the relation is as:

```
Programs --> Sessions --> Worksheets
```

At some point in application I want to display list of Worksheets for selected prgram in a tabular form as:

```
--------------------------------
|Worksheet Name | Session Name |
--------------------------------
|Worksheet 1    | Session 2    |
|---------------|--------------|
|Worksheet 3    | Session 1    |
|---------------|--------------|
|               |              |
```

My question is whether I should go for embedded documents i.e embed sessions in prgram and worsheets in session, or should I go for seperate collections for program, session and worksheet and relate them using concept similar to foreign key in RDBMS?

My concern is, if I go for seperate collections then for above scenario I will have to perform too much queries to get above result.

If I go for nested documents querying the subdocument is quite limited.

There is a limit of 16MB for a document in mongo, which is more than enough if I go for nested document. So document size is not my concern.

As mongo is not basically meant for ralation and normalization, So my question is whether I should go for normalized schema with relations or should I go for de normalized data with embedded documents taking in account my above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, the guiding principle for data modeling is to design your documents so that fulfilling your application's most common queries is easy and fast. This is very different from schema design in RDBMS's, which focuses on normalizing the data to formalize the relations between different parts of it and then relying on joins to be able to get the right information back by denormalizing across the relations. It's not true that MongoDB isn't "meant for relations". It is true it does not handle normalized data as well as an RDBMS because it does not perform joins. Joins must be done application-side.

Pontification finished, a simple way to model your data that makes your query easy is to store worksheets as documents, denormalizing session and program data into each worksheet

```
{
    "_id" : "p3s1ws0",
    "session_id" : "s1",
    "program_id" : "p3",
    ....
}
```

then you retrieve all worksheets for a given program_id `prog_id` with the query

```
> db.worksheets.find({ "program_id" : prog_id })
```

most likely adding a sort to produce the desired tabular form. Another realistic option is to have session documents with an array of worksheet documents inside, assuming the number of worksheets per session can be limited to a reasonable number, say 200:

```
{
    "_id" : "s0",
    "program_id" : "p2",
    "worksheets" : [
        {
            "_id" : "ws0",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

The query remains the same

```
db.sessions.find({ "program_id" : prog_id" })
```

since you can get all the worksheets for a session from each session. Depending on exactly how you want to make the tabular form it might be worthwhile to use aggregation for the query, but there's no sign of a need for it in the question.

The choice between the two depends on how it will affect your other queries and updates. For example, updating program information is more expensive for the first model, because it needs to be updated for every worksheet in the program, as opposed to updating every session in the program, or as opposed to updating just one document if the data were modeled as a program document with arrays of sessions containing arrays of worksheets (probably don't want to do that).

To read more about this kind of data modeling, I'd suggest William Zola's [classic series](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) from the MongoDB blog.